# Rust match mutable enum reference with vectors

Tags: vector, enums, rust, move

I'm trying to change an enum's **named property** but getting this error.

```
cannot move out of a mutable referencerustc(E0507)
parser.rs(323, 36): data moved here
parser.rs(323, 36): move occurs because `statements` has type `std::vec::Vec<std::boxed::Box<ast::ast::StatementType>>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

I saw that we can change enum's named props with match statements. But I couldn't understand why there's a move occurrence, since I'm borrowing the enum itself. Here's the code:

```rust
        match &mut block {
            StatementType::Block { mut statements, .. } => {
                statements = block_statements;
            },
            _ => panic!()
        };
        return block;
```

I've tried mem::swap too but still it's the same error:

```rust
        match &mut block {
            StatementType::Block { mut statements, .. } => {
                // statements = block_statements;
                std::mem::swap(&mut statements, &mut block_statements);
            },
            _ => panic!()
        };
        return block;
```

**BUT** when I do this:

```rust
                std::mem::swap(&mut *statements, &mut *block_statements);
```

The error changes to:

```
the size for values of type `[std::boxed::Box<ast::ast::StatementType>]` cannot be known at compilation time

doesn't have a size known at compile-time
```

Types are:

- StatementType is an enum that derives Clone
- Block is mutable variable of StatementType
- Block's `statements` is a variable of `Vec<Box<StatementType>>`
- `block_statements` is another variable of `Vec<Box<StatementType>>`

Please do not say that it happens because statements' type is Vector: come with a solution as I can read error messages too.

Comment: Can you provide a playground example ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to think what the type of `statements` is and what you would like it to be.

With the code as you wrote it, it is of type `Vec<_>` (sorry, I said it), but since the `match` captures the block by reference, it cannot take the contents by value, hence the error. Note that the error is not in the assignment but in the match brace itself:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of a mutable reference
  --> src/main.rs:15:11
   |
15 |     match &mut block {
   |           ^^^^^^^^^^
16 |         StatementType::Block { mut statements, .. } => {
   |                                --------------
   |                                |
   |                                data moved here
   |                                move occurs because `statements` has type `std::vec::Vec<std::boxed::Box<StatementType>>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

You would like `statement` to be of type `&mut Vec<_>` of course. And you get that by using the `ref mut` capture mode:

```
    match block {
        StatementType::Block { ref mut statements, .. } => {
            *statements = block_statements;
        },
        _ => panic!()
    };
```

And remember to use `*statement` when assigning, as it is now a reference. You could also use a `mem::swap` if you want, of course:

```
            std::mem::swap(statements, &mut block_statements);
```

But note that you do not need to `match &mut block` but you can do `match block` directly.

There is this thing called *match ergonomics* that lets you match against a reference and omit the `ref mut` capture mode, that makes your code easier to write and understand:

```
    match &mut block {
        StatementType::Block { statements, .. } => {
            *statements = block_statements;
        },
        _ => panic!()
    };
```

The problem in your original code is that if specify any capture mode then match ergonomics is disabled.

Comment: Thanks, got it working now. About the solution, you're saying that if I use Vec (or any unsized type) I need to use `ref mut` capture mode, am I right?

Comment: @Skai: It has nothing to do with unsized types. If you want to capture a field of a complex type without consuming the whole object you have to capture by reference. The `mut` is just to get a mutable reference, instead of a regular one.

Comment: @Skai: That weird object about unsized types arises because you used operator `*` directly with a `Vec`, not a reference, and since `Vec` implements `Deref<[T]>` you get a `[T]`, that is unsized and cannot be swapped.